# Stack View not properly aligning

Tags: swift, uistackview

I have this layout using stack view, but when run in simulator it doesnt quite scale well,

[image]

This is how i aligned them in the scene.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked to see if your constraints are correctly setup on your StackViews?

Comment: @CStreel hi, your right, constraint was not properly configure, but then when i set the constraint the red pane was quite smaller,, not sure if this is still a constraint issue,, I edited the image above... thanks

Comment: I haven't used stackviews yet, so my ability to help you stops here sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the views inside the stackView should have aspectRatio constraint set.

Alse don't forget the set your stackView in the following way:

[image]

Comment: hi, I updated the above image,, but still the red pane does not scale to the size that i intended,,, what could be the proper aspectRatio of the view?

Comment: 1:1 would be the proper ratio of this grey square. Is is difficult to anticipate what exactly you are trying to achieve, but in order to make each of grey squares scale properly, 1:1 is the right ratio

Comment: Ah thanks for the hint,,, one thing that i forgot was to set the Distribution on the parent StackView ,,, it should be set to Fill Proportionally,, to have it scale according to what you've set initially..